# Restore SQL Server database from .sql files

Tags: sql, sql-server

So we had an encrypted database that puked and killed our whole SQL Server setup. Sucks about our data, but we were smart enough to have our Data structure/Stored Procs/Functions in Git

The problem is they're saved as `.sql` files.

Is there any way we can batch restore our schema from directories full of these files?

I've looked around and I can only find tutorials for restoring from `.bak` files or `.mdf`'s. This isn't the lazy man's way out- I just need to find a solution ASAP. Any advice or resources/ anything at all would be greatly appreciated.

Thanks Interwebs,

Dylan

Comment: You need to (1) get your SQL Server up and running again, (2) create the database using appropriate parameters (like sizes etc.), and then (3) execute the `.sql` scripts one by one on that new database

Comment: Was looking for more of a batch solution. But using sqlcmd seems to be the key. Will post solution when done

Comment: Did you not have backup files for your databases?  Including your system databases?

Comment: That was encrypted too >.<

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Considering the large size of the data structure I was trying restore, running each files individually was not a practical solution. I'm sure I could have written a bat fie, but I got it done pretty quickly in python:

```
import os, subprocess
processDir = 'C:\\Database-master\\'
files = os.listdir(processDir)
for f in files:
    db = processDir + f
    #potentially drop corrupt db and create new ones with f
    scripts = os.listdir(db)
    for script in scripts:
        path = db + '\\' + script
        proc = subprocess.Popen('sqlcmd -S 127.0.0.1 -i "' + path +'"', shell=True)
        proc.wait()
```

Comment: The problem that you're going to have is getting them in the right order.

Comment: For some reason it didn't seem to matter. I know in Management Studio you can't create functions or procedures based off non-existent tables- yet sure enough using sqlcmd I was able to create the proc before the table. Eg: dbo.SP_update_Claims.storedprocedure.sql ran despite its dependency on dbo.update.table.sql

Weird much?

Comment: Not really.  Stored procedures aren't usually a problem because they support deferred resolution.  Views are usually the problem, because they cannot be compiled/saved unless all of their constituent tables/views already exist.  This may go unnoticed because some groups will prefix the names of their views with the letter "V".  So, if the scripts are executed alphabetically, then the views may get executed after all of the tables.

Comment: Of course it may also just mean that your method of executing the scripts is suppressing any errors and you may later discover that there is a bunch of stuff missing.

Comment: We don't have any views. Maybe that's a fault on our end, but we generally keep all relationships scripted out. That's good to know though

Answer (score 1):

If your database was large/complex the real problem you are going to encounter is not batch execution but the order in which scripts should be executed.

Unless you have some backup file this is going to be the real problem here.

If you only have your scripts then I'd suggest something like this.

1. tables
2. views
3. everything else...

Just execute one query after another until you get an error. When you do encounter an error this is most probably because you are trying to reference object that doesn't already exist. Just save that script for later and continue with executing scripts. Then start from the beginning again and go through scripts that caused an error. Now objects are probably there. Repeat this as many times as needed until you create all your objects.

Comment: I don't think it would be much more of a step to parse out the type. In my instance, I don't think it proved to be much of a problem. But it's good to know